# serial data output on arduino GPIO

Tags: serial-port, arduino

How do I have serial data come out of an arduino's GPIO pin? I don't mean for the serial monitor but an 8 bit number? Then, how do I get another arduino to read that number correctly through one of it's GPIO pins? Basically, I'm trying to make a serial network between two arduinos without using the UART pins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) implements a software UART.